# How to write this regular expression correctly in Kotlin to test the code in Pascal

Tags: kotlin

I tried to do this, not quite the right solution, because if you remove the semicolon, it will still be **true**, but it should be **false**

**Here is the assignment:**
Checking the correctness of the for statement, in which the initial and
non-integer values ​​can be either integers or symbols, and the body of the loop is the write(ln) operator, whose arguments are integers and
real numbers and variables.

Sample Pascal code to check:

```
for i:=1 to n do
  write(0);
```

---

My attempt to implement this regex on Kotlin:

```
fun main(){
        val regex = Regex(pattern = """for\s\w:=\d|\w\sto\s\w|\d\sdo\nwrite(\w|\d);|writeln(\w|\d);""")
        val matched = regex.containsMatchIn(input = "for i:=1 to n do\n write(n);")
        if(matched) println("True")
        else println("False")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Regex are in general not powerful enough for checking context free languages. So you can't check the syntax of an arbitrary pascal source with regex. It may be possible for your short example, but there are a number of problems with your regex

- `(` and `)` are part of regex syntax (grouping). Thus if you want your string to literally contain `(` and `)` you have to escape them like `\(` and `\)`
- Your alternatives are not clearly specified. So for instance `for\s\w:=\d|\w\s....` will match anything before `|` or anything after it. Use grouping to exactly specify your alternatives. `for\s\w:=(\d|\w)\sto`
- All your matches for variablenames or numbers only match a single character. So something like `for i:=1 to 10` won't be matched. Use `\d+` or `\w+` to also match multi-digit numbers/longer variable names
- Same for whitespaces `\s` Your regex always expects exactly one whitespace. The indention from your original example won't be matched.
- `\d` (all digits) is a subset of `\w` (all word characters, a-zA-Z0-9_) , so `\d|\w` can just be `\w`. But in pascal, variable names cannot start with a number, so you have to do `(\d+|[a-z]\w*)`, ie either a number or a variable name starting with a character.
- You don't consider real numbers (1.23) at all. So instead of `\d+` you have something like `\d+(\.\d+)?` (still totally neglecting that .3 or 2.3e4 are valid real numbers as well)
- You can simplify `write|writeln` by `write(ln)?`

So taking this all together your regex could look something like this

```
val regex = Regex(pattern = """for\s+[a-z]\w*\s*:=\s*(\d+|[a-z]\w*)\s+to\s+(\d+|[a-z]\w*)\s+do\s*(\n|\s)\s*write(ln)?\((\d+(\.\d+)?|[a-z]\w*)\);""")
```

Comment: This line, outputs false, although it should output true "for i:='1' to 'n' do\n write(n,7.54,-6,7e7);"

Comment: @roxyashechka  Why would you consider `for i:= '1' to 'n' ...` valid pascal syntax? Where are the quotes coming from? And as mentioned above, this regex does not cover the case of `7e7` to be a valid double number. And why do you have multiple argument in the write statement? This was also not specified in the original question ...

Comment: @derpirsher 
The fact is that I was not entirely aware of the accuracy of the code being checked, on that day I was shown how the code that is being checked should look like

Comment: @derpirsher
The task itself sounds like this:
Using functions that implement work with regular expressions,
develop a program for checking the syntactic correctness of fragment
that programs in Pascal (classical dialect) in accordance with
your option (the option number in this work differs from the previous
breathing).
Checking the correctness of the for statement, in which the initial and
non-integer values ​​can be either integers or symbols, and
the body of the loop is the write (ln) operator, whose arguments are integers and
real numbers and variables.